# WPF windowstate

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-code, windowstate

form does'nt open in maximum size even though I set in wpf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cezYn.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dob6E.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you set your height to 600px, and that's exactly what it looks like in the picture you provided. Try removing that.

Comment: 1 or 2 hours ago it was full screen with the same codes but now it's only half the screen size

Comment: written code does not give an error, only my application does not go full screen

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning,

I have done its with c# :

```
 this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: İt Doesn't work